# How Can I add an Event that play the keys according with the keyboard in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, keyboard

I need to play a drum according to the key pressed on my keyboard. The only things that I've done is make it play when I click with the mouse.

This is the HTML. The sound tags has the standardized name for javascript create a dinamic id at the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>DrumKit Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="container_h1">JavaScript Drum Kit</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="container_header">
        <div class="header__key_mapping">
            <h2 class="container_h2">Key Mapping</h2>
            <ul class="keys__mapping">
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">E</p> Crash</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">R</p> Ride</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">F</p>Floor tom</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">G</p>Mid tom</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">H</p>High tom</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">V</p><p class="keys text">B</p>Kick</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">J</p>Snare</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">I</p> Hi-Hat Open</li>
                <li class="keys__mapping_key"><p class="keys text">K</p>Hi-Hat Closed</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

    <main class="container__main"> 
        <img src="assets/drum-img.png" alt="drum image" class="container__header_img">        
        <div class="container__main_btns">
            <button class="btn key_crash" onclick="onclick()" id="">E</button>
            <button class="btn key_ride" >R</button>
            <button class="btn key_floor-tom" >F</button>
            <button class="btn key_mid-tom" >G</button>
            <button class="btn key_high-tom" >H</button>
            <button class="btn key_kick" >V</button>
            <button class="btn key_kick2" >B</button>
            <button class="btn key_share" >J</button>
            <button class="btn key_hit-hat-open" >I</button>
            <button class="btn key_hit-hat-closed" >K</button>
        </div>
 
        <audio id="btn-key_crash" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/crash.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_ride" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_floor-tom"  src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/tom-low.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_mid-tom" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/tom-mid.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_high-tom" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/tom-high.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_kick" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_kick2" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_share" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_hit-hat-open" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/hihat-open.wav"></audio>
        <audio id="btn-key_hit-hat-closed"  src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/hihat-close.wav"></audio>
    </main>
<footer></footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add the function that plays the sounds of the drum according with to key of the keyboard, but I didn't manage it.

```js
function playKey(idKey) {
  const element = document.querySelector(idKey);
  if (element) {
    element.play();
  } else {
    console.error('element nof found')
  }
}

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  const key = btns[i];
  const keyCode = key.classList[1];
  const idKey = `#btn-${keyCode}`;

  key.onclick = function() {
    playKey(idKey);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the relevant HTML. I ask as splitting the `classList` is very brittle and needs to be refactored, but also so we can see how the `audio` elements are arranged and relate to the keys pressed

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to play different audio when different keys are pressed and for that you can use `keydown` event to track key presses and also know which key was pressed.

Here in the below code snippet we can catch which key was pressed. And then based on that you can play different audio as per your requirement.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
  console.log(key);
// Play audio as per requirement
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Hi</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can dispatch the event on key press and subscribe to the event to perform different actions. Which in your case might be playing different audio based on key.

You can dispatch event by for e.g. this:

document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key': 'H'}));

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.